# Pricing depending on selected items in a multi step form

Tags: forms

I'm looking for a way to create a custom pricing for my clients. Depending on the options they choose on a multistep form. I'm using Wordpress

For example first, the user is being asked if he needs a car. If he answers yes the price goes up and he comes to the next step where he is being asked if he needs a ride home etc. each time he or she selects an option or not the price changes or stays the same. And each of these questions appears alone on the screen.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Greetings!

Comment: That is a very broad question. Are you asking us to do it for you or is there a particular part of this project that you are stuck on?

Comment: Ah sorry for sloppy formulation! I'm looking for ideas on how I can start this project. Are there any plugins I can use, so I don't have to code it?